# How To Regen Farm On BTD5 Mobile

Tags: bloons-td-5, mobile

I was wondering how can I regen farm the most efficiently on BTD5 mobile, while also having a back-up option in case I start to get over run by regrows to end the farm. Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: Use a ground zero (plane) to end the farm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrow farming requires many different conditions to work right.

1. Round: Obviously, regrow farming needs to be on a round with a large regrow rush. Round 49 is the best, because, being before round 50, and containing a regrow rainbow rush, you get full XP and Money.
2. Farming Towers: These are the towers that are going to keep the farm running. Recommended is a 3-X wizard, if you have a good computer upgrade to 4-X after a minute and even place more. If for some reason wizards won't work (Restricted tower on a special mission, Glitches...), Ninjas with distraction, Bloonchippers, and the Banana Farmer pro will work okay if needed.
3. Popping Towers: During Regrow farming, things can quickly get out of control. In order to control the bloons, a tower is needed that can pop the rush near the end, without destroying the farm. The Ring of Fire tower is, despite what you may think, very bad at controlling the bloons. 4-X Cannons can pop Zebra and blacks, and I strongly recommend them. A few of them can power through any rainbow rush

Comment: I thought the best round was 42.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea for XP, I'll show to prepare:
Use a 1/0 Engineer Monkey, and get 7 or 8 farms over the next 22 rounds. Upgrade the farms to at least 3/0. Getting hard? Upgrade the engineer with 9-inch nails and get a 2/2 or 2/3 Apprentice. When reaching any of the rounds that are only regrows, like round 42, use some towers that will knock back the bloons (Like Downdraft), Slowers (Glue gunners at level x/4), Multipliers (Ice Monkeys at Artic Wind), Poppers (The Ray of Doom's good for popping, but **DO NOT TRY TO SWIPE AT ALL THE BLOONS!**.), and Farmers (Like some Sprockets Engineers).

Comment: Also, at the intermission before farming round (after beating the round before it) sell your towers.

Comment: Round 42 has rainbow camos as well. Mind to fix your answer, Cameron Brown? P.S. I recently posted a question about the bloonchipper, I want a answer, but don't really want to do a bounty, so I'm going to upvote any answers. Hope you know the answer to my question. :)